# Dexguard : Instruction has invalid constant index size

Tags: android, maven, obfuscation, build-error, dexguard

I am getting the following error while integrating Dexguard 8.5 version. I am trying to use the latest feature of downloading the Dexguard jars from a secure maven. My license file is located at the root directory of my project.

[image: Error log]

As suggested by an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217563/keep-logging-while-obfuscating-with-dexguard), my dexguard-project.txt have only 3 to 4 encrypted strings namely, "android.content.pm.PackageInfo","packageName", "versionName","versionCode".

Can someone please explain where the issue can be?